# Statistical relationship between the stages of a stochastic optimization problem

Tags: bayesian, optimization, independence, causality, probabilistic-programming

What exactly do the "stages" of a [stochastic program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_programming) say about the **statistical relationship** between the problem variables?

From what I understand, the stages imply both an **"ordering"** and **"grouping"** of variables. What are the semantics of such designation of variables?

For example:

1. Is it correct to say that stages are a modeling **assumption** of the **statistical relationship** between the problem variables?
2. What's the **information theoretic** nature of that relationship?

#### Example:

In a typical "two stage" (e.g. production) stochastic program one often distinguishes between:

- "First-stage" decisions (variables)
- "Second-stage or "recourse" decisions (variables)

In terms of their statistical dependency or **Bayesian relationship**, is it correct to say that this simply states that:

- **1st** stage variables are **"realized"** (decided) **independently** of **2nd** stage variables
- The realization (decision) probabilities of **2nd stage** variables depend on the realization of **1st** stage ones?

Or is there anything deeper to it?

---

In case it helps, I [found the following](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/471/2944) in our sibling [SE.OR](https://or.stackexchange.com/) site:

> Oe might confuse the notion of time periods and stages in stochastic programming. [Quoting from [King and Wallace](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387878164)'s book on page 16]:
>
> “*We should not confuse information stages with time periods. Stages model the flow of information; time periods represent the ticking of the clock in a model. Stages, on the other hand, are points in time where we make decisions in the model after having learned something new*.”

Answer (score 1):

The staging does not explicitly state anything about the statistical relation of the variables, but rather tells us which *conditional distributions* we care about.

For example, suppose some variable A is a first stage variable and B is a second stage variable. Then, the two probability distributions we care about are $P(A)$ and $P(B | A)$. This is because at the first stage, we care about the value of $A$, which is unknown. Since $B$ is also unknown, what we care about is the marginal distribution of $A$. At the second stage, we know $A$ and care about $B$, thus we are working with $P(B|A)$. In contrast, the distribution $P(A|B)$ is irrelevant for our stochastic program.

Note that this doesn't tell us anything about these quantities. For example, nothing restrains us from having $A$ and $B$ independent, although if we know they are, our problem just got easier.

Why is this important? Well, in traditional probability courses, we always think about computing the conditional distribution from a joint distribution. In statistics, we often **ignore** the joint distribution and directly model a conditional distribution. As an example, in logistic regression we often model $P(Y|X)$. However, we generally skip the step of modeling $P(X)$ and thus $P(Y,X)$. So in our staging example, we know that we need to model $P(A)$ and $P(B|A)$, but we can skip modeling $P(B)$ and $P(A,B)$. Note that in general, modeling joint distributions is considerably harder than conditional distributions!

Comment: Thanks Cliff, but I am not sure I follow. If staging tells us _"what conditional distributions we care about"_, how is that **not** telling us something about the statistical relationship between the variables? e g. Moreover, wouldn't variable staging tell us something about the causal relationship between them in the theorized (presumed) scenario where observing the values of A would "cause" us to later choose (optimize) the values for B? Or maybe staging at a minimum tells us how we are choosing to factorize their joint distribution?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina: I updated my answer to help clarify.

Comment: Thanks. That helps a bit, but something here is still not clicking for me, sorry. you say: _The two probability distributions we care about are () and (|)_ but why is that? There must be some assumption we are making about "information flow" (I don't personally like this term, but that's the exact quote from "King and Wallace"'s book on stochastic programming). That "information flow" must come from a statistical assumption or relationship between these variables. If it's not e.g. causality on some theorized scenario, which is a form of statistical relationship, what is it?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina: I'm not sure I'd say it's an assumption about the model, but rather it's an assumption about the decisions we will need to make. If our stochastic program framework is correct, then we will never need to make choices regarding $A$ when we already know the values of $B$, so in that problem, modeling $P(A|B)$ should never be helpful to us. Since we will need to make decisions about $B$ when $A$ is known, modeling $P(B|A)$ will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Cliff. For the same problem, can one get different solutions if we model the problem as 1) single stage, 2) two staged, and/or in the case of the latter, if 3) we swap what variables we place in each stage?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina: sure! If you treat it as a one stage problem, then we can't use the information in $A$ to refine our actions with regards to $B$, so we should expect that the one stage solution should be worse than the two stage solution on average.

Comment: Thanks Cliff - that's what I also understood :) so from that perspective, IMHO it's an assumption about the model, but maybe it's semantics!

Comment: [This](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2016/01/5285.pdf) seems to cast some light into the "information flow" between variables . As a modeler, one could theoretically develop a sense of how informative some variables may be about the optimal result and optimal value of variables in e.g. subsequent stages, then compare that to the complexity cost of adding more stages, and finally decide if it's worth it to pay the price of extra stages. In other words, the modeler could choose to compromise the quality of the solution based on how informative and valuable those stages are.

Comment: I guess you meant to write "The staging does **not** explicitly state anything" (typo)?

Comment: @desertnaut: wow that was a huge typo. Thanks, fixed.